# Unity Gradle Build Fail: processReleaseManifest due to attribute conflict

Tags: gradle

After a bunch of hoop jumping, I've gotten close to fixing whatever started this problem in the first place. My current, and hopefully last, hurdle is fixing a gradle error that's claiming I've got conflicts within my AndroidManifest.xml files.

```
stderr[
D:\Projects\MyCompany\MyGame\Game\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.3.2] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:4:3-30:17 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.3.2] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:4:3-30:17 to override.
```

To address this issue, I opened the 3 AndroidManifest.xml files I could find within my Unity project folder. Within those files, I couldn't find a single instance of 'appComponentFactory'. I have no idea which AndroidManifest.xml file they are suggesting I add the tools:replace tag to; however, I tried putting it into one of them and only got merger errors.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: I feel like I've tried every possible combination of SDK Tools versions and Facebook SDK versions, and no matter what I do, I get Gradle errors. This is incredibly frustrating, especially since I haven't done anything since the last build I made. I'm hoping someone replies with some insight, I'm running out of options.

Comment: So apparently nobody on SO can help me with this? That's disappointing...